# Recursively select (with limited depth) relationships in SQLAlchemy using ORM, declarative style, and Association objects

Tags: python, postgresql, recursion, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Given:

```
DIRECTIONS = db.Enum('N', 'NE', 'E', 'SE', 'S', 'SW', 'W', 'NW',
                     name='directions')


class Exit(BaseModel):
    __tablename__ = 'exits'
    src = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('room.id'), primary_key=True)
    dst = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('room.id'), primary_key=True)
    direction = db.Column(DIRECTIONS, primary_key=True)
    from_room = db.relationship('Room', foreign_keys=[dst],
                                backref=db.backref('exits',
                                                   lazy='dynamic'))
    to_room = db.relationship('Room', foreign_keys=[src]))
```

Using:

SqlAlchemy 0.9.8, PostgreSQL 9.3.5

**How do I query to recursively select exits to some depth `n` given a starting room `r`?**

Example (A Simple Map):

```
                           E                                               
                          /                                                
                B   C -- D                                                 
                 \ /                                                       
                  A                                                         
                  |                                                         
                  F                                                         
                 / \                                                        
                G   H                                                       
                     \                                                      
                      I
```

Supposing the relationships could be represented by the map above,

- What query would give me all the rooms, starting with some arbitrary room?
- How could I limit the above query to a certain number of 'hops' from the original room?

  - E.g., starting with `A`, select all rooms except `E` and `I`, by limiting depth to 2.

Of course, I can do this in Python:

```
rooms = [starting_room]                                                     
for exit in starting_room.exits.all():                                      
    if exit.to_room not in rooms:                                           
        add_to_map(exit)                                                    
        rooms.append(exit.to_room)                                          
for room in rooms[1:]:                                                      
    for exit in room.exits.all():                                           
        if exit.to_room not in rooms:                                                       add_to_map(exit)                                                
            rooms.append(exit.to_room)
```

But this is expensive and not suitable for more than 2 hops.

I have tried following the [CTE](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.SelectBase.cte) examples in the SQLAlchemy docs, but it is difficult to grok how to make it work for an Association Object like I have, particularly as I have no experience working with CTEs in pure SQL.

My attempt:

```
>>> starting_exits = db.session.query(Exit).filter_by(from_room=starting_room).came='starting_exits', recursive=True)
>>> start = orm.aliased(starting_exits, name='st')
>>> exit = orm.aliased(Exit, name='e')
>>> cte = starting_exits.union_all(db.session.query(exit).filter(exit.src == start.c.dst))
>>> db.session.query(cte).all()
```

hangs indefinitely, even if I slice it (`.all()[:5]`). What should I be doing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I hope I did not overcomplicate your model, but in order to test the query (which follows below) I used the following model definition:

#### The MODEL:

```
class Room(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'room'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)

    exits = association_proxy(
        'lnk_exits', 'to_room',
        # creator=lambda v: Exit(to_room=v),
        creator=lambda k, v: Exit(direction=k, to_room=v),
    )
    entries = association_proxy(
        'lnk_entries', 'from_room',
        # creator=lambda v: Exit(from_room=v),
        creator=lambda k, v: Exit(direction=k, from_room=v),
    )


class Exit(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'exits'
    src = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('room.id'), primary_key=True)
    dst = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('room.id'), primary_key=True)
    direction = Column(DIRECTIONS, primary_key=True)

    from_room = relationship(
        Room, foreign_keys=[dst],
        # backref='lnk_exits',
        backref=backref(
            "lnk_exits",
            collection_class=attribute_mapped_collection("direction"),
            cascade="all, delete-orphan",
        )
    )
    to_room = relationship(
        Room,
        foreign_keys=[src],
        # backref='lnk_entries',
        backref=backref(
            "lnk_entries",
            collection_class=attribute_mapped_collection("direction"),
            cascade="all, delete-orphan",
        )
    )
```

You really do *not* need to use the relationships the way I did, but I like the way I did it because it allows me to work on the relationships between the rooms as below:

```
# Insert test data
rooms = [Room(name=name) for name in 'ABCDEFGHI']
session.add_all(rooms)

A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I = rooms

A.entries = {'NW': B, 'NE': C, 'S': F}
B.entries = {'SE': A}
C.entries = {'E': D, 'SW': A}
D.entries = {'W': C, 'NE': E}
E.entries = {'SW': D}
F.entries = {'N': A, 'SW': G, 'SE': H}
G.entries = {'NE': F}
H.entries = {'NW': F, 'SE': I}

if True:  # add cycle, in which case we get duplicates in the results
    B.entries['E'] = C
    C.entries['W'] = B

session.commit()
```

*You can read more on this in the [`Association Proxy`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html#module-sqlalchemy.ext.associationproxy) section of the documentation.*

#### Now the QUERY

Please note that in order to use the query below you do not need any of the association proxy and related stuff above. Current query hangs even with simple relationship `A <--> B` because you the `CTE` will navigate it back and forth indefinitely. So the trick is to add `level` information to the `CTE` so that you can limit your search on the level. The query below should get you started:

```
# parameters
start_id = session.query(Room).filter(Room.name == 'A').first().id
max_level = 2

# CTE definition
starting_exits = (session.query(Exit, literal(0).label("level"))
    .filter(Exit.src == start_id)
    .cte(name="starting_exits", recursive=True)
)
start = aliased(starting_exits, name="st")

exit = aliased(Exit, name="e")
joined = (session.query(exit, (start.c.level + 1).label("level"))
    .filter(exit.src == start.c.dst)
    # @note: below line will avoid simple cycles of 2, which does not always help, but should reduce the result-set significantly already
    .filter(exit.dst != start.c.src)
    .filter(start.c.level < max_level)
)

cte = start.union_all(joined)
for x in session.query(cte).order_by(cte.c.src, cte.c.dst, cte.c.level):
    print(x)
```

I assume you are only interested in second column (`dst`) of the resulting query in order to get `id` of the `Room`s you can reach. Probably also column four (`level`) would be of interest in order to find the *shortest* path to that room. But you might still get multiple ways to the same target room, so please filter those out ex post.

**Edit:** A simple way to use `cte` in order to get the rooms (model instances) would be:

```
# get all Rooms (no duplicates)
s = session.query(cte.c.dst.distinct().label("room_id")).subquery(name="rooms")
q = session.query(Room).join(s, Room.id == s.c.room_id)
for r in q:
    print(r)
```

**Edit 2:** To get the exits as well as the rooms (model instances) in order to reconstruct the graph, simply do another join on the query above:

```
exits = (session.query(Exit, Room)
         .join(s, Exit.dst == s.c.room_id)
         .join(Room, Room.id == s.c.room_id))
for exit, room in exits:
    print exit, room
```

Comment: Now that the CTE query is working partially, I can see that it is giving me tuples (I guess representing rows from the database) instead of returning objects, I guess because this leverages the lower-level expressions. I have been working and programming mostly with the ORM in my humble 2 weeks with SQLAlchemy. How should I go about making the two play nice?

Comment: Even without objects, how would I combine this with a join to at least get the room names in the tuples?

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist: see update at the end of the answer. If you only need room names, then instead of `query(Room)` do `query(Room.name)`.

Comment: This is wonderful. Thank you! I learned a hell of a lot of SQLAlchemy from this one answer. :)

Comment: Great, and SQLAlchemy [documentation](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/) is really great!

Comment: I actually find the documentation terribly difficult to understand when it comes to parts like this that I'm less familiar with in pure SQL. But I haven't yet grokked SQLA. One more question, if I might: I still don't understand this query well enough to understand how to keep the _relationship_ intact. It's not just the room names, but the associated exits (where that room is the exit.src) I'm after.

Comment: I'm basically trying to generate a connected graph from the adjacency list, you see.

Comment: So what do you really want to see as the end result? Please provide sample output based on your graph.

Comment: This way of getting the list of rooms is fine; I just don't understand how I would be able to reconstruct the graph from it without knowing the directional connections. The only way I know to do that is room.exits.all() (which is another trip to the database -- the entire point of this question was to figure out how to do it in one trip). The point is to be able to draw a representation of the graph like I did in the question, out to some distance from the starting point, limited by a specified number of hops.

Comment: I finally came back to this and had a 'DUH!' moment when I realized what I should have been doing: `exits = session.query(Exit, Room).join(s, Exit.dst == s.c.room_id).join(Room, Room.id == s.c.room_id)` then `for exit, room in exits:` -- mind if I edit the final solution as the last line of your answer? (or you can)